# How to show "Why did this render" In React Dev Tools Profiler

Tags: reactjs, react-native-debugger

I am reading this article about profiling React applications: [Optimize slow React components](https://reallifeprogramming.com/investigate-poor-performance-react-components-with-react-profiler-86be7d7364b3) and in the Profiler you can see "Why did this render" in the tooltip and sidebar:

[image]

[image]

Where as in my profiler there is no such information. I am using the latest version of React Native Debugger:

[image]

How can I see / display this information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a setting for that, which is disabled by default apparently:

[image]